# Strict Equality (===) versus Shallow Equality Checks in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, comparison, equality

I'm studying how Hooks APIs provided by **React-Redux-v.7.1** works, and saw it mentioned in **Equality Comparisons and Updates** (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) that:

"*As of v7.1.0-alpha.5, the default comparison is a strict **===** reference comparison. This is different than **connect()**, which uses shallow equality checks on the results of **mapState** calls to determine if re-rendering is needed. This has several implications on how you should use **useSelector()**.*"

I'm wondering **why strict equality is better than shallow equality that used by *connect()***? Then I looked into their equality comparisons:

The default strict equality check of [*useSelector()*](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L25) is simply checking *a===b*

```
const refEquality = (a, b) => a === b
```

And the equality checks in [react-redux/src/connect/connect.js](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/0c048f0646754de103cc2d9825762340bed06119/src/utils/shallowEqual.js#L11-L35) is using *Object.is()* and also other checks, which is same as that in [react](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a9b035b0c2b8235405835beca0c4db2cc37f18d0/packages/shared/shallowEqual.js#L19-L51).

```
// The polyfill of Object.is()
function is(x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    return x !== 0 || y !== 0 || 1 / x === 1 / y
  } else {
    return x !== x && y !== y
  }
}

export default function shallowEqual(objA, objB) {
  if (is(objA, objB)) return true

  if (
    typeof objA !== 'object' ||
    objA === null ||
    typeof objB !== 'object' ||
    objB === null
  ) {
    return false
  }

  const keysA = Object.keys(objA)
  const keysB = Object.keys(objB)

  if (keysA.length !== keysB.length) return false

  for (let i = 0; i < keysA.length; i++) {
    if (!hasOwn.call(objB, keysA[i]) || !is(objA[keysA[i]], objB[keysA[i]])) {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}
```

According to [the description of Object.is() in MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) "***Object.is** does no type conversion and no special handling for NaN, -0, and +0 (giving it **the same behavior as === except on those special numeric values**).*"

I have no idea why *a === b* is better than a series of equality checks.
(It's my first time asking questions here, apologize for rudeness or lack of information)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With `connect`, `mapStateToProps` returns a composite object of all of the state being selected from the store, so a shallow comparison across its keys makes sense. With `useSelector`, the pattern is often to only return a single value for each invocation of `useSelector`, similar to the way that the `useState` hook only handles a single value instead of all of the state values. So if each call to `useSelector` returns a value directly then a strict equality check makes sense vs a shallow comparison. A short example should make this more clear.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {keyA: state.reducerA.keyA, keyB: state.reducerB.keyB}
);
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Here `mapStateToProps` is called every time the store changes in any way, so the return value will always be a new object, even if `keyA` and `keyB` do not change. So a shallow comparison is used to decide if a re-render is needed.

For the hooks case:

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

function MyComponent(props) {
  const keyA = useSelector(state => state.reducerA.keyA);
  const keyB = useSelector(sate => state.reducerB.keyB);
  ...
}
```

Now the result of the `useSelector` hooks are the individual values from the store, not a composite object. So using strict equality as the default here makes sense.

If you want to use only a single `useSelector` hook that returns a composite object, the docs you linked to have an example of using the `shallowEqual` equality function: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates

Comment: Thank you, it's very clear to me! So it's not about which one is better, but depends on how they work. Thanks again for the speedy answer and clear examples :D

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure if I was getting my point across very clearly in words alone - I'm glad the examples helped.

Comment: Is it possible for this react redux hook to trigger and return a new object when there are no updates to any of its fields?